# DotTrace detaches after sent start command

Tags: dottrace

I am attempting to use the DotTrace command line tool self profile my application (I would use the NuGet, but it has a [blocking bug](https://github.com/JetBrains/profiler-self-api/issues/6).)

It starts up just fine.  I create the dotTrace process and attach it to my application.  I then use standard in to send it the `"##dotTrace["start"]` command.  I have done this in a demo app and my real app.  In the demo app, it starts profiling after that command is sent.

In my real app it responds with `"##dotTrace["disconnected"...`  as if I had sent a `##dotTrace["disconnect"]` command.

It does not give any indication why it detached, just does it as if I had requested it.

**How can I figure out why detach was called?**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the profiler crashed just after start. Could you please add `--core-log-mask=55` to the dotTrace command line? It will generate a log file in `%temp%\JetLogs`. Please, share the folder `JetLogs` after that.